# Can these sentences be the same premise?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I have these two sentences:

```
Blonde girls have some dolls
Only blonde girls have some dolls
```

and I have reached the same point:  ∀x (G(x)∧B(x)→ ∃y (H(x, y)∧D(y)) ) where

```
G (x) -> x is a girl
B (x) -> x is blonde
H (x, y) -> x has y
D (x) -> x is a doll
```

I've been thinking about it for a while. What do you think? Are we talking about the same?
Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that all girls have dolls. Then the first sentence is true, and the second is false.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The second is false? Why doesn't the quantifier specify "only blonde girls"?

Comment: The second sentence says that the only girls who have dolls are blonde girls; no redheaded girls or brunette girls have dolls. Your first-order expression is not a correct translation of that sentence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think I understand what you are explaining... So, to express the second sentence I should interpret "having dolls implies being a blonde girl"? i.e.  ∀x (∃y (H(x, y)∧D(y)) → G(x)∧B(x) ) ? I will review it more, thanks.

Comment: Yes, ‘having dolls implies being a blonde girl’ works fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your help, studying this I have realized that sometimes we don't understand well what we mean. :-) Have a nice day.

Comment: You’re very welcome. You too!